# Program "Day" 75% Working... Help JAVA

Tags: java, class

75% of my code works, this part works fine for my assignment... I have gotten parts a-e

It is the following I cannot get to run with that part of the code...

- F. Calculate and return the day by adding certain days to the current
  day.  For example, if the current day is Monday and we add four days,
  the day to be returned is Friday.  Similarly, if today is Tuesday and
  we add 13 days, the day to be returned is Monday.
- G. Add the appropriate constructors.

Any advise on how I can structure what I wrote, to get it to compute with the first part?

```
import java.util.*;
/* 
Personal information
*/
public class MyDayIIII
{
static Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates common input object class
String d1;                                     // Private member variable 

public MyDayIIII(String d1)                //Constructor of value Sunday
{
d1 = "Sunday";
}
public void setD1(String theD1)           //Assigns value for user's input for "set day"
{
d1 = theD1;
}
public String claimD1()                   //Displays user's day
{
return d1;
}
// print the day, looks unnecessary
public void printD1()
{
System.out.println("Printed Day: " + d1);
}
// return the next day
public String tomD1()
{



// using direct comparison will fail as day == "Saturday"?
// so use compareTo() method...
if(d1.compareTo("Saturday") == 0)
return ("Sunday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Sunday") == 0)
return ("Monday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Monday") == 0)
return ("Tuesday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Tuesday") == 0)
return ("Wednesday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Wednesday") == 0)
return ("Thursday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Thursday") == 0)
return ("Friday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Friday") == 0)
return ("Saturday");
else
return ("\"Please Capitalize the First Letter of Your Day(e.g. Monday)\"");
}
// return the previous day
public String SetprD1()
{
if(d1.compareTo("Friday") == 0)
return ("Thursday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Thursday") == 0)
return ("Wednesday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Wednesday") == 0)
return ("Tuesday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Tuesday") == 0)
return ("Monday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Monday") == 0)
return ("Sunday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Sunday") == 0)
return ("Saturday");
else if(d1.compareTo("Saturday") == 0)
return ("Friday");
else
return ("\"Please Capitalize the First Letter of Your Day(e.g. Monday)\"");
}

public static void main (String args[])
{
MyDay testday = new MyDay("Sun");
System.out.print("Enter A Day(First Letter Capitalized & Full Spelling) ");
// read and store user's day
String storeday = readinput.nextLine();
// invoke setDay() method to set a day defined by user
testday.setDay(storeday);
// invoke getDay() method to get a day
System.out.println("You Chose: " + testday.getDay());
// test printing by invoking printDay() method
testday.printDay();
// invoke getPreDay() method to get the previous day
System.out.println("Day Prior Is: " + testday.getPreDay());
// invoke getNextDay() method to get the next day
System.out.println("The Following Day Is: " + testday.getNextDay()); 
}
}
```

I keep trying to insert this, to get it do part F. 
It will start, but I get the following...

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at TextCalculator.main(TextCalculator.java:24
```

So I take it out, of the original... Can anyone give me any feedback, I am getting frustrated...

My goal was to create an array of 7 elements, and then compute future date by using a modulus of 7, and have it correspond to the value of the elements...

```
String[] day = new String[7];

day[0] = "Monday";                  //Elements were assigned the day of the week for their    value
day[1] = "Tuesday";
day[2] = "Wendesday";
day[3] = "Thursday";
day[4] = "Friday";
day[5] = "Saturday";
day[6] = "Sunday";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a Number for Future Days:");     //Prompting user to input number of days

String future = scanner.nextLine();

int futureDay = Integer.valueOf("future");

int numDay = day.length % 7;     //Using value of elements, with modulus 7 to assign value     and determine placement

while (numDay >= day.length)     
{
numDay -= day.length;
}
```

Comment: It's a school assignment, I write my codes separately and then put them together... It is easiest for me to visualize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your code says

```
int futureDay = Integer.valueOf("future");
```

when it should be

```
int futureDay = Integer.valueOf(future);
```

NOTE the no quotes around future.  This is because "future" is a String with the characters f,u,t,u,r,e (and obviously not an integer) where as `future` is the name of a  variable you declared previously.

Comment: Thanks! I thought placing it in quotes is how I would convert the value of the string to integer form... It is computing now, but now every time I enter a digit, it give me the future data as Monday?